# Can "some" be used in "if" clause?

Tags: word-choice

We can say "If you have any questions, please let me know." Then can we say "If you have some questions, please let me know."? Or what's the difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: "Some" means more than one, "any" means one or more. But saying "any questions" is more common, it's a set phrase.